# Blogdown and Data Files

Tags: r, blogdown

I'm just starting with Blogdown and am running into an issue. I wrote a post where I've read a .CSV file and then generated a Kable table from its contents. No sweat. However, when I build the site that CSV file is copied to "public/post/data". I do not want that file to be made available to the public since it contains proprietary information (the columns I've pulled for this table are public info, but other columns are not). I do not think that the CSV file is needed on the public webpage once it is built, but I cannot find a way to not upload it.

I've tried putting the .CSV file in different locations (the "resources" folder and another folder I created named "data_files"). I added .CSV to the ignoreFiles param in config.toml: ignoreFiles = ["\.Rmd$", "\.Rmarkdown$", "_files$", "_cache$", "\.csv$"] Nothing, though, seems to help.

Is there some way to use a .CSV file to generate a table, ggplot, etc. without having that file uploaded to the public website?

Here's the code chunk where I read the CSV file in case that will help.

````
```{r peerList, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}

dataloc <- here("resources","peers.csv")
df <- read.csv(dataloc)

names <- select(df,Name,City,State,County,Zip) %>%
  mutate(Zip = str_sub(Zip,1,5)) %>% # change the 9-digit zips to 5
  mutate(County = str_replace(County,"County","")) %>% # del the word 'county'
  arrange(State,Name)

kable(names, "html") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped",
                full_width = F,
                position = "center"
                )

```
````

Comment: I think what you did is fine by putting the `\\.csv$` in the `ignoreFiles`. I suspect the reason it appears it is not working is because the csv got copied into the public folder before you did this. Try deleting it from the public folder and repeating it again and it shouldn't be there anymore.

Comment: That would be my guess, too. Hugo won't delete the `public` folder each time you rebuild the site.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I discovered from the answer to another question that my `ignoreFiles` line was misplaced. I simply moved it closer to the top of the config.toml file and it started working -- then the .csv file was not copied. It seems to make a difference where that line appears.